# Celery - Memory Leak (Memory doesn't get free even after worker completed the task)

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a atomic transaction running on celery server which consumes lot of memory but memory doesn't get free after task is completed.

Solution which worked for me is to kill the celery worker after N tasks i.e. to use - **CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD**.

Is there any other solution to this problem?
what should be good number to set for **CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD**, If celery receives around 10,000 tasks per day

Comment: In most cases the memory is available for use in the Python process again, but not freed in the OS. You should not have any problem if there are no other processes taking large amounts of memory.

Comment: No, there is no other way other than fixing the memory leak...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4843) on celery which may be worth checking out.

Your workaround is quite fair and is what we used in our own business and simply worked. The remarkable thing is that celery uses worker pools which means it doesn't kill worker processes after each task and reuses them for the next tasks, which obviously means process level resources can be leaked over time.

You can measure the time it takes for processes to start and die. For example if your tasks take 20s and it takes 2 seconds for the processes to start and finally die and you tolerate an overhead of 5% then you can set the `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD` parameter to 2. It depends on the amount of overhead and leak you can tolerate.

Comment: You can configure that (to create new process aver N tasks executed), if you want (and that is recommended when you know your tasks are leaking memory).

Comment: That's exactly what @RajatJain has stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks  @DejanLekic and ali,  I  think we all ended up to common solution and I decided to got CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 200.
Also I am analysing code for memory optimisation....cheers